# How autocall method in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have scene with label which shows what part of hardware are being checked at the moment, so i need invoke "checkMethod" automatically after scene has been drawn, how can i do it in JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do something when the Scene is shown:

```
stage.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkMethod();
            }
        });
```

You also have this other methods:  setOnCloseRequest, setOnHidden, setOnHiding, setOnShowing.

---

The option proposed in comments Its the followin:

```
scene.windowProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Window>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Window> arg0,
                    Window oldVal, Window newVal) {
                if(oldVal != null){
                    oldVal.setOnShown(null);
                }
                if(newVal != null){
                    newVal.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            checkMethod();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: As i understood correctly, end of drawing is something like type of action?

Comment: Basicly that eventhandler will be "Called just after the Window is shown". And inside the handler you can do what you think its apropiate, in this case, call checkMethod

Comment: You are talking about stage or scene?

Comment: Scene is a container for the scene graph and has no logic about showing/hiding, that logic belongs to the Window or Stage.

Comment: I think you didt understand my problem correctly.. I know that scene has no logic about showing/hiding, but i need it.. Thats the reason i wrote there..

Comment: What you can do then, if it works for you its add a change listener to the WindowProperty of the scene, and when this one changes add the .setOnShown event handler to the new stagge/window, and remove it from the old one... The result should be the same as having the handler on the scene itself.